# IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2 Constant Value

Tags: c#, c++, c, winapi

I'm working on code that calls into the WinAPI, specifically into DeviceIoControl. It takes an IoControlCode which for the following control code is as follows:

IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX = 0x220448

However it is important for me to be able to retrieve the USB protocol accurately (i.e. Usb11, Usb20 or Usb30) and for that I need to call IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2. I cannot find out what the constant value I should be passing into DeviceIoControl is. I've looked on pinvoke.net under the Constants section and they have no documentation on this new-ish call and accompanying structs.

Can somebody educate me as to where I might find this const value?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't feel like digging through the headers, and decoding the `CTL_CODE` macro- open Visual Studio, create a C++ console application and do something like this:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <usbioctl.h>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    cout << "0x" << hex << IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2 << endl; 
    // Output: 0x22045c
    return 0;
}
```

Be lazy. Let the compiler tell you what the value is.

Answer (score 0):

In usbioctl.h and usbiodef.h from the Windows Kits include\shared folder:

```
#define IOCTL_USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2  \
                                CTL_CODE(FILE_DEVICE_USB,  \
                                    USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2,  \
                                    METHOD_BUFFERED,  \
                                    FILE_ANY_ACCESS)

#define USB_GET_NODE_CONNECTION_INFORMATION_EX_V2   279

#define FILE_DEVICE_USBEX               0x00000049
```